# Issue with Core Data fetch request

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm quite new to iOS Development and I'm having some issues with a Core Data fetch request. I'm using Xcode 9-beta and swift 4.

Whenever I update my database, I'm loading the new data with a fetch request, to make some calculations and fill a table view.

My challenge is that every time I do a fetch request for an entity, I'm getting the same data, even though it changed. It seems to me that is reusing the data from a previous fetch request, because if I close the app and open it again, it shows me the new stored data.

Here's my code:

```
if let context = container?.viewContext {
        context.perform {

            let request: NSFetchRequest<EntityName> = EntityName.fetchRequest()
            let data = try? context.fetch(request)
            self.data = data!

            self.setUI()
        }
}
```

I'm getting the container from:

```
let container: NSPersistentContainer? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer
```

I gave some generic names, as I think that's irrelevant for the question.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
JL

Comment: Are you getting any errors or output into the console?

Comment: Fetch requests are never reused. Perhaps you forgot to **save** the context after changing the data. Btw: the persistent container and the managed object context are supposed to be non-optional and `AppDelegate` is mandatory otherwise the application won't launch. It's not evil to forced unwrap the objects: `let container = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors into the console. And I am saving the context every time I change the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the viewContext from the container because I needed the UI thread. I guess that was my problem. I solved it passing the context I used to fetch and create the data and dispatching the request to the main queue:

```
func loadData(with context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

    context.perform {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let request: NSFetchRequest<EntityName> = EntityName.fetchRequest()
            let data = try? context.fetch(request)
            self.data = data!

            self.setUI()
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't getting any errors. Maybe it because after changing you didn't save context

Are you sure that you did that?

This method helps you to save context right after changing

```
  private func saveContext() {
    guard managedObjectContext.hasChanges else {
      return
    }
    do {
      try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
      abort()
    }
  }
```

try to find it in `AppDelegate`

UPDATE:

It's also maybe because `.perform` is async, and after you update data, it didn't save yet.

> asynchronously performs the block on the context's queue. 
>   Encapsulates an autorelease pool and a call to processPendingChanges

Comment: I do save context. Also, I know that it is working because when I close the app and open it again, it shows the updated data, so I'd say it has to do with the fetch request. And yes, it's in the AppDelegate file.

Comment: when you updating UI, is it main thread? because context.perform is async. If you change smt and save in async, maybe data still saving, or still loading. Try to find it and debug.

Comment: It is main thread, because otherwise I would be getting an error. Also, I get true when using: `Thread.isMainThread`